# How can clipping be prevented on a Qt QLabel?

Tags: qt-designer, clipping, qlabel

I have a dialog created in Qt Designer with contents that resize when the window is resized.

[image: image resized correctly]

When the window height is made too small, the text in the window clips as follows:

[image: labels clipped]

How do I prevent the labels from being clipped?

Most specifically, the window must not resize any smaller than the size of the word wrapped text without clipping.